# Экспорт таблицы QTableWidget в .xlsx

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, xlsx, qtablewidget

Имеется таблица **`QTableWidget`**.

По нажатии на копку `'Save'`  открывалось бы диалоговое окно для выбора имени файла и директории для сохранения содержимого таблицы.

Содержимое сохранялось бы в **`.xlsx`**.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt

# Наследуемся от QMainWindow
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # Переопределяем конструктор класса
    def __init__(self):
        # Обязательно нужно вызвать метод супер класса
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.setMinimumSize(QSize(480, 80))             # Устанавливаем размеры
    self.setWindowTitle("Работа с QTableWidget")    # Устанавливаем заголовок окна
    central_widget = QWidget(self)                  # Создаём центральный виджет
    self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)           # Устанавливаем центральный виджет

    grid_layout = QGridLayout()             # Создаём QGridLayout
    central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)   # Устанавливаем данное размещение в центральный виджет

    table = QTableWidget(self)  # Создаём таблицу
    table.setColumnCount(3)     # Устанавливаем три колонки
    table.setRowCount(1)        # и одну строку в таблице

    # Устанавливаем заголовки таблицы
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3"])

    # Устанавливаем всплывающие подсказки на заголовки
    table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setToolTip("Column 1 ")
    table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setToolTip("Column 2 ")
    table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setToolTip("Column 3 ")
    qbtn = QPushButton('Save', self)

    # Устанавливаем выравнивание на заголовки
    table.horizontalHeaderItem(0).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
    table.horizontalHeaderItem(1).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
    table.horizontalHeaderItem(2).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

    # заполняем первую строку
    table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("Text in column 1"))
    table.setItem(0, 1, QTableWidgetItem("Text in column 2"))
    table.setItem(0, 2, QTableWidgetItem("Text in column 3"))

    # делаем ресайз колонок по содержимому
    table.resizeColumnsToContents()

    grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)   # Добавляем таблицу в сетку


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я проверил для вас некоторые библиотеки, которые вам помогут
сохранять данные из таблицы в `.xlsx`, а также читать `.xlsx` и помещать данные в таблицу.

```
import xlrd                                                      # pip install xlrd

# XlsxWriter - это модуль Python для создания файлов Excel XLSX.
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook                         # pip install XlsxWriter

from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(self)            
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget) 
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = QMenu("&File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        self.actionOpen = QAction("Open", self)
        self.actionSave = QAction("Save", self)        
        fileMenu.addAction(self.actionOpen)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.actionSave)
        self.actionOpen.triggered.connect(self.fileOpen)
        self.actionSave.triggered.connect(self.fileSave)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget() 
        _data = {
            '0': ["Hello", "", ""],
            '1': ["", "World", ""],
            '2': ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
            '3': ["hello", "world", "777"]
        }
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(_data[list(_data.keys())[0]]))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(_data))                                       
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(1)
        for row, data in _data.items():
            for column, value in enumerate(data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(int(row), column, QTableWidgetItem(value))
        
        self.main_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)        

    def fileSave(self):
        fileName, ok = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self,
            "Сохранить файл",
            ".",
            "All Files(*.xlsx)"
        )
        if not fileName:
            return 

        _list = []
        model = self.tableWidget.model()
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            _r = []
            for column in range(model.columnCount()):
                _r.append("{}".format(model.index(row, column).data() or ""))
            _list.append(_r)
        print(fileName)
        
        workbook = Workbook(fileName)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet() 

        for r, row in enumerate(_list):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)        
        workbook.close()  
        msg = QMessageBox.information(
            self, 
            "Success!", 
            f"Данные сохранены в файле: \n{fileName}"
        )            

    def fileOpen(self):
        fileName, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            'Open file',
            '.',
            "PersonDoc files (*.xlsx)"
        )
        if not fileName:
            return
            
        data = xlrd.open_workbook(fileName)
        table = data.sheets()[0]
        nrows = table.nrows
        ncols = table.ncols
 
        self.tableWidget.clear()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(nrows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(ncols)

        for i in range(nrows):
            for j in range(ncols):
                if isinstance(table.row_values(i)[j], str) == False:
                    newitem = str(table.row_values(i)[j])
                else:
                    newitem = table.row_values(i)[j]
                newitem = QTableWidgetItem(newitem)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j,newitem)


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @follow_the_sun пожалуйста